# Convert split interval coordinates to continuous interval coordinates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, intervals

I have a `data.frame` where each `id` maps to several discontiguous linear intervals, which do not overlap, and are sorted in ascending order:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep("id1",3),rep("id2",4)),
                 start = c(101,220,307,550,658,742,855),
                 end = c(154,246,326,625,712,811,944),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'd like to add new `start` and `end` columns that will cumulatively sum up the interval widths and show the cumulative start and end coordinates.

So, for the example `df` above, these new `start` and `end` columns (`cum.start`, `cum.end`) will be:

```
df$cum.start <- c(1,55,82,1,77,132,202)
df$cum.end <- c(54,81,101,76,131,201,291)
```

Any `dplyr` way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lag` and `cumsum`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(cum.start = c(1, lag(cumsum(end - start + 1))[-1] + 1) ,
         cum.end = cumsum(end - start + 1))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    start   end cum.start cum.end
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 id1     101   154         1      54
#> 2 id1     220   246        55      81
#> 3 id1     307   326        82     101
#> 4 id2     550   625         1      76
#> 5 id2     658   712        77     131
#> 6 id2     742   811       132     201
#> 7 id2     855   944       202     291
```

Comment: I think everyone has had similar ideas so I won't post another answer. Variation - `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(newend = cumsum(end - start + 1), newstart = lag(newend + 1, default=1))`

Comment: @thelatemail I actually did it like that at first, but didn't feel like rearranging the columns (although that'd be more efficient probably).

Answer (score 2):

Please find below one possible solution with `dplyr`

- Code

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate( diff = end-start+1,
               cum.end = cumsum(diff),
               cum.start = cum.end - diff + 1) %>% 
  select(-diff) %>% 
  relocate("cum.end", .after = last_col())
```

- Output

```r
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    start   end cum.start cum.end
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 id1     101   154         1      54
#> 2 id1     220   246        55      81
#> 3 id1     307   326        82     101
#> 4 id2     550   625         1      76
#> 5 id2     658   712        77     131
#> 6 id2     742   811       132     201
#> 7 id2     855   944       202     291
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You need to `group_by(id)`.